# Firebase signInWithPopup() function, pop-up google sign in Window but the pop-up does not show any google accounts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I am doing "Google Sign In Authentication" using firebase... but the sign-in pop-up window does not show any available google users, and the pop-up window disappears after about 5 sec and does not do anything.

**Code in firebase.js :**

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/firestore";
import "firebase/auth";

var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyDSxAzARyErU6gr7ujsEfg2hB6DYz02OnA",
  authDomain: "crwn-db-3c771.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://crwn-db-3c771.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "crwn-db-3c771",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "395022734699",
  appId: "1:395022734699:web:39122ca48383548f"
};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const auth = firebase.auth();
export const firestore = firebase.firestore();

const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
provider.setCustomParameters({ prompt: "select_account" });
export const signInWithGoogle = () => auth.signInWithPopup(provider);

export default firebase;
```

**Code in sign-in.jsx :**

```
import { signInWithGoogle } from "../../firebase/firebase.utils";


class SignIn extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
          <CustomButton onClick={signInWithGoogle}>
            Sign in with Google
          </CustomButton>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SignIn;
```

The signInWithGoogle pop-up window should show available google accounts, from which I select one and it continues, and register that user in firebase authentication user.
But the pop-up does not show any available google account (there are two logged-in accounts in my browser), and the pop-up disappears automatically after about 5 sec.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fowzR.png)

Comment: Can you check the browser console for any errors?

Comment: I think this is not the firebase problem. please check the CustomButton component which you passed onClick as props.

Answer (score 9):

If you want Firebase `signInWithGoogle` to stop and ask which google account to sign in to before using the current auth token you will need to use the `setCustomerParameters` method and manually invoke the prompt like so...

```
var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
provider.setCustomParameters({
  prompt: "select_account"
});

//works for signInWithPopup and signInWithRedirect

const signInWithPopup = () => auth.signInWithPopup(provider);  
const signInWithRedirect = () => auth.signInWithRedirect(provider);
```

Link to `setCustomerParameters` [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider#setcustomparameters)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like normal the behavior for the case where the user actually got signed in automatically using the Google account that was also signed into Chrome.  Add an auth state listener and add some logs that check to see if the user is actually signed in at that point.

Comment: It does not sign in at all... The pop-up dont show any available accounts and disappears after some time ( 5s ), and in google authentication users there is no user added...

Comment: What are you observing that indicates the user was not signed in?  Please edit the question to state very clearly how you know this.

Comment: I know this by two things... firstly, the sign-in pop-up window doesn't show any google accounts which I can select ( so how can it authenticate any user), the pop-up then disappears. Secondly, there is no user added in authentication -> users

Comment: for your information, i am a starter at firebase and reactj

Comment: Please **edit your original question** with your observations, don't comment on my answer.  Also look in the console log for information.

Comment: @DougStevenson, Hey Doug, You're absolutely right, however how can I avoid this behaviour?  I developed a web app that uses Firebase Auth through signInWithPopup(), so 99% percent of the times the popup shows and I can choose the account I want to use to login, but from time to time the popoup closes itself and my app tries to login a user logged in Chrome with a google account, but who hasn't previosuly created an account within my app so the app crashes (not registered in my app), do you have any idea how to solve this issue? tnx!

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#set_an_authentication_state_observer_and_get_user_data

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue, i rebooted my mac and it worked perfectly. if that error still exists, try this:

instead of this

```
export const signInWithGoogle = () => auth.signInWithPopup(provider);
```

use this:

```
export const signInWithGoogle = () => auth.signInWithRedirect(provider);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to enable the provider? For your example you have to go into your project in firebase, go to Authentication tab, then click on Sign-In Method and check if Google is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same problem. I enabled 3rd party cookies on my chrome and It worked So Please try this also.

Comment: Aman, it is great to see you participate, can you provide more details in how this is done and explain why 3rd party cookies were needed in your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I also same problem. but I solved it.

```
const data = await signInWithPopup(authService, provider);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export const signinWithGooglePopup = () => signInWithPopup(auth, provider);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what your code does and how is answers the question?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue where it was working fine but then it stopped working, if your chrome browser needs to be updated this will happen.

however, you should also do

```
export const signInWithGooglePopup = () => 
                          signInWithPopup(auth, Provider)
```