# ionic 7 firebase auth login with google on ios fails to work

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

On ios when i tap the button it does nothing. 2nd time on tapping throws the below error

```
[error] - ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/cancelled-popup-request).
wt@capacitor://localhost/main.fb958ec84f30377a.js:1:254648
create@capacitor://localhost/main.fb958ec84f30377a.js:1:255133
cancel@capacitor://localhost/main.fb958ec84f30377a.js:1:895314
```

The code works fine on testing in web browser though. Here is how it looks like

```
 async login() {
    console.log("trying to sign in with google")
    return await signInWithPopup(this.auth, new GoogleAuthProvider())
  }

<ion-button class="ban-full-button" (click)="doLogin()"><ion-icon slot="start" name="logo-google"></ion-icon>Login</ion-button>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

There were other issues (like "[Firebase signInWithPopup() function, pop-up google sign in Window but the pop-up does not show any google accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57843505/6309)") reported with [`signInWithPopup`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.Auth#signinwithpopup)

Check if the issue persists with  [`signInWithRedirect` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.Auth#signinwithredirect) instead, since the popup method is not always reliable in mobile environments.

```js
async login() {
    console.log("trying to sign in with google")
    const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
    return await signInWithRedirect(this.auth, provider)
}
```

Then, get the result with [`GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.googleauthprovider#googleauthprovidercredentialfromresult):

```js
getRedirectResult(this.auth)
  .then((result) => {
    // This gives you a Google Access Token.
    const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
    const token = credential.accessToken;
    const user = result.user;
    console.log(user);
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

---

If you're using a [Capacitor plugin](https://capacitorjs.com/) like [`@codetrix-studio/capacitor-google-auth`](https://github.com/CodetrixStudio/CapacitorGoogleAuth), you don't need to call `getRedirectResult`: the plugin handles the sign-in flow. It will return a `Promise` that resolves to the user's information (including the ID token) once the user successfully signs in.

```js
import { GoogleAuth } from '@codetrix-studio/capacitor-google-auth';

async login() {
  const user = await GoogleAuth.signIn();
  console.log(user);
}
```

And a button in your HTML page:

```html
<ion-button class="ban-full-button" (click)="login()"><ion-icon slot="start" name="logo-google"></ion-icon>Login</ion-button>
```

Comment: Also, are you using [Capacitor](https://capacitorjs.com/)?

Comment: yes i am using capacitor

Comment: @MoblizeIT OK. I have edited the answer to include a section using Capacitor.